# service to send and receive audio clips with server

Tags: android, audio, service, server

Okay my goal is to run a background service to open a connection to a personal server which will continually send audio clips from other users logged onto same said server. All clients will be recording short audio to upload and be dispersed to others. Essentialtalk group push to talk. Is there an api designed for this already? What while be the best way to go about this in my Android app?? Any particular type of server best suited to implement this?

Comment: Did you consider using GCM and how much have you done ?

Comment: Gcm? Ui is completely mostly. As well as the record process and write to internal. Along with extra byte file with senders" user info to be uploaded. Server will collaborate byte files to create user list per port to send out